# JS FileReader How to get the contents of the.txt file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

`<input type="file" id="file-selector" accept=".txt" ref="fileSelector">`

```
const fileSelector = document.getElementById('file-selector');
    fileSelector.addEventListener('change', ()=>{
      const reader = new FileReader()
      reader.readAsText(fileSelector.files[0],'utf8') // input.files[0]为第一个文件
      reader.onload = ()=>{
        document.body.innerHTML += reader.result  // reader.result为获取结果
      }
    }, false)
```

in Vue,I want Read the txt file in JavaScript,what is wrong with above code

Comment: Honestly, i don't have an idea about Vue, but as a JS developer, i see that your code looks good and correct, i guess it would be recommended if add to your post the HTML part of your selected elements to see if it was defined well,
I tested this code [here in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sohaieb/qbw8g7un/1/)

Comment: If the posted code doesn't work in your app, there must be something wrong with how you're using it in Vue. Please update your question with a *runnable* [mcve], containing the bug. In short, you should show how it doesn't work.